# google js api reverse geocode wrong address from LatLng

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a real trouble trying to start my web app because of wrong adress returns from Google Geocoder when passing LatLng values to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/3kUx7/

```
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latLong}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    if (results) {
```

The main problem is that coordinates pair **50.393386951159684,30.612979531288147**
returns the wrong address "улица Заречная, 9А"

The same pair tested in new and old google maps and even regular google search returns correct address "Днепровская наб., 26Г, Киев, город Киев 02000"

The code i use for reverse geocode is the same as in jsfiddle.
That area was newly built (5-7 years ago :) ) adn google has some wrong building on a regular map but address almost correct.

Reverse Geocoding Test App
http://reverse-geocoding.appspot.com/
gives the SAME WRONG RESULT but showing 2014 copyright!

I just don't understant what am i doing wrong. Or google has different DBs for online maps and JS API. if so GOOGLE PLEASE SYNCRONIZE! The world had changed for past 5 years!

Comment: This is Stackoverflow, not Google, we're not able to update their data

Comment: The thing is that:"Starting today, the Maps API team will shift most of its efforts for supporting the community’s technical Q&A to Stack Overflow."it was on 10.02.12

Comment: The SO-community is not able to fix their wrong data

Comment: i understand that :) i have posted a bug report at [link](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6662). i really thought that i'm doing smth wrong getting data from coordinates and spent half a night to investigate the situation. it was really strange behavior to get correct data from one coords and wrong data from another. I'm afraid that i'm not the one gone crazy over that. I tried to serach inet but the most useful thing i found was Test App so i could check and found that its a real difference between interfaces.